Question regarding the proof of estimation of ODE
We have the following Lemma from Koiso, Page 8:

If $a,b \in L^1, a \geq 0$ and $\left| a \right|_{L^1} > 0$, the equation \begin{align*}  - v '' + a v = b \end{align*}
has a unique solution; moreover, $ v \in C^1$ and is bounded by
\begin{align}
&\max \left|  v \right| \leq 2 \left( 1+\frac{1}{\left\| a \right\|_{L^1}} \right) \left\| b \right\|_{L^1} \\ 
&\max \left|  v ' \right| \leq 2 \left( 1+{\left\| a \right\|_{L^1}} \right) \left\| b \right\|_{L^1} 
\end{align}

The proof is the following.

Question: How does one see that $$v(q) \geq v(p) - B ? $$ I think it's because of the fact that $-B \leq v'(x)$, but shouldn't that be $-B(q-p) \leq v(q) - v(p)$ according to FTC?
